# No module named 'azure.storage'; 'azure' is not a package

Tags: python, azure, package, storage

I am working with azure blob storage.
I have installed it using command **pip install azure-storage-blob**
when i am running **pip freeze** command I can see it is installed as the version **azure-storage-blob==12.9.0**

but When i am importing it in my python file as

```
import azure.storage.blob
```

I am getting this error

No module named 'azure.storage'; 'azure' is not a package

I have tried different python 3.8, 3.6 and 3.9 but still there is the same problem.

Comment: Which version of Python did you install it with? I just installed it with 3.10.1 and it imported fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the below steps to install the package:

1. Add the required modules in requirements.txt
2. Open cmd and enable virtual environment for python with below commands.

   ```
    python -m venv .venv
    .venv\Scripts\activate
    pip install -r requirements.txt
   ```

If the issues not fixed with above steps, check the sitepackages in your local and compare all the modules, functions, and files with [Azure SDK for Python documentation.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/azure-eventhub-checkpointstoreblob-aio_1.1.4/sdk/storage)

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead

```
python3 -m pip install <package_to_install
```